# Can arguments be passed just by reference to function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Look at this:

```
addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){..code..},false);
```

can be written as

```
function mouseover(e){ ... }
addEventListener('mouseover', mouseover, false);
```

So here `mouseover` function receives event object even though it was just referenced and not passed any parameters. I'd think that maybe `addeventlistener` function executes all functions referenced/anonymous like this:

```
....
suppose like this
function addeventlistner (a,b,c){
b(e);
}
```

Why I am asking this?

I can't understand where `e` come from in `addeventlistner` function `function (e) {...code...}`.

As I understand this second parameter of `addeventlistner` can be either target object or function. Which is passed an event object. It makes sense that function can do something with object passed to it, what does the object would do with this passed event object.

the reason for this is that I was trying to understand in some example codes that function took e from `addeventlistner`, similar to one above, and used properties like e.msg, e.data, and e.cmd..... which I have no clue where they are coming from.

Are they properties of Event object? I can't find them!

Comment: Link to where e.data, e.msg, and e.cmd is used: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: learned: 1. message can be object.(e.data returns object) 2. event has types which has specific properties to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an event listener the function you add gets passed an event object depending on what type of event it is (click, scroll, etc).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    alert(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
}, false);
// same as
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert(e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY);
}, false);
```

The parameter name can be anything it still represents the event object.

**EDIT** List all of the properties and functions of an event object

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var all = "";
    for(var prop in event) {
        all += prop + " : " + event[prop] + "\n";
    }
    alert(all);
}, false);
```

Comment: oK...But do events have properties as well. i have found that there multiple type of events. And each has its own properties. W3schools doesnt have message event, as expected. Mouse event would x and y properties. Where is the list of all properties associated with specific events.

Comment: @Muhammad Umer - Events have unique properties associated with their event type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event  lets you dig into the different event types and show their properties. I'll also add some code to my answer you can iterate through all of the properties/methods of the event object.

Comment: I figured it out....e.data is THE property of event type 'message'. There are types of events with different properties. Like mouse event would have x and y. So message one had data property. e.cmd and e.msg were actually more like e.data.cmd...message could be either string/object/arraybuffer. In this case it was object so cmd was user defined property which could have been anything. :D

Comment: @Muhammad Umer - glad you figured it out.